# Sumar registro de dos tablas con relacion MYSQL

Tags: mysql, date

Tengo la siguiente duda que no eh podido resolver, lo tratare de explicar un poco y ya después pongo algo de código, para poder aportar un poco.

Tengo dos bases de datos.

1. **Psb_smt**
2. **scrap**

Dentro de la base de datos **"Psb_smt"** tengo una tabla llamada **"produccion"** , proporciono los datos clave para reducir y no escribir todos.

1. psb_line <- **Nombre de la linea**
2. scrap <- **Relacion para la tabla "scrap"**
3. DateTime <- **Hora del registro**

Dentro de la base de datos **"scrap"** tengo una tabla **"registros"** y son los siguientes campos.

1. fecha <- **Hora del registro**
2. linea <- **Relación que va al campo "scrap" de la tabla "psb_smt"**
3. total <- **Campo que guarda valores de costos.**

El objetivo o lo que quiero lograr, es hacer una suma del campo **"total"** de la tabla de **"registros"** pero necesito saber a que linea pertenecen de la tabla "psb_produccion" por eso las relaciono con el campo "scrap" en "psb_produccion" y en "registros" con el campo "linea" y pues que la única condición es que sean en determinada fecha y las dos tablas cuentan con campos de fechas, anexo unas fotos y la consulta que yo tengo pero que aun no cumple con el objetivo.

Tabla **"psb_produccion"** subraye de color rojo los campos que mencione arriba el campo "scrap" es de la relacion con la otra tabla, contienen el mismo dato para hacer el left join.

[image: 1]

Tabla **"registro"** de la base de datos **"scrap"**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta el momento esta es la consulta que yo tengo obteniendo los datos que necesito pero con una suma incorrecta ya que la suma que me arroja es duplicada por el numero de registros que tiene esa linea en la tabla de "psb_produccion"

```
SELECT SUM(psb_produc)/SUM(psb_rate) AS TotalProd,
B.id,B.linea,F.linea, B.DateTime,B.EndDate,A.id_employee,A.id_empatarollos,
MAX(E.description) AS HourF, 
SUM(F.total) AS TotalScrap
    FROM psb_smt.psb_produccion A
    INNER JOIN psb_smt.psb_info B 
        ON A.id_psbinfo = B.id
    INNER JOIN psb_smt.psb_hours E  
        ON A.psb_hr = E.id_desc
    LEFT JOIN scrap.registro F  
        ON A.scrap = F.linea AND
        F.fecha>= '2020-03-03 06:40:00'  AND F.fecha<= '2020-03-03 16:10:00'
    WHERE A.DateTime>= '2020-03-03 06:40:00'  AND A.DateTime <= '2020-03-03 16:10:00' AND A.hour_psb = '1S_HOURS' AND A.statusdtp=0
    GROUP by B.linea
    order by TotalProd DESC
```

Me da el siguiente **resultado**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Un Total de "80" y esto es incorrecto ya que para este ejemplo solo hay un registro en la tabla de "registros" para esta linea, anexo imagen encerrando de color rojo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi conclusión y mi problema hasta donde lo he visto hasta ahora es que la suma me la hace los números de registros que tenga de la linea de la tabla "psb_produccion" por que hice un solo registro en la tabla "registro" con un total de "20" y generando la consulta que yo tengo me da un total de "80" en mi tabla "psb_produccion" hasta el momento tengo 4 registros, multiplicándolo por 20 da un total de "80" esta de mas explicarlo así pero lo estoy detallando.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esos son los registros que tengo en "L-02 (SMT)" espero que me puedan ayudar o me puedan corregir con este problema, estoy al pendiente de sus respuestas.

Comment: porque utilizas left join en la tabla scrap.registro? deberia ser inner join

Comment: @Manny Hola buen dia gracias por comentar, lo pongo por que necesito que me mi consulta me muestre la informacion de las lineas aunque no exista un valor en el campo, si uso el inner solo me muestra el registro que si tiene valor en el campo.

Comment: entonces tienes que especificar en el where esa excepcion algo como diferente de null  y usa inner join

Comment: Da la impresión que quien multiplica los registros es `psb_smt.psb_hours`¿qué pasa si comentas ese `INNER JOIN` junto con `MAX(E.description)`?

Comment: @Sal sigue igual me sigue multiplicando la suma del total por el numero de registros que tiene la linea

Comment: ¿Y sin `psb_info`?

Comment: @Sal lo sigue duplicando por el numero de registros que tengo en psb_produccion de tal linea.

Comment: No es fácil entender el contexto viendo imágenes por aquí y por allá. Quizá ayude que nos expliques brevemente: 1º. todas las relaciones que hay entre las tablas, 2º. qué quieres obtener (brevemente explicado), 3º. el por qué de cada elemento de tu consulta. Por ejemplo, no entiendo por qué esto pasa a formar parte de un criterio para un `JOIN` y no para un `WHERE` en general: `AND
        F.fecha>= '2020-03-03 06:40:00'  AND F.fecha<= '2020-03-03 16:10:00'` En problemas como estos la sencillez ayuda. Como está la pregunta ahora es complicado tener una visión contextual para poder ayudarte.

Comment: @A.Cedano La relacion que tengo entre la tabla "psb_produccion" y "registros" es la de el campo "Scrap" con el campo "linea", lo que yo quiero es obtener la suma de el campo total pero ese es el problema que me esta duplicando la suma por el numero de registros que hay en psb_produccion de determinada linea, y pues meto la condicion de fecha en mi left por que en la otra tabla de "registros" tambien manejo fecha, entonces si no lo pongo me hace suma de toda la tabla.

Comment: Pero en tu consulta hay más tablas y más JOIN, debes explicar todas las relaciones que hay y no en un comentario, sino editando la pregunta. Yo leí tu planteamiento, pero no logro entender el contexto. Otra cosa que puedes hacer es subir un fiddle con las tablas y parte de datos para poder verlo sobre el terreno. Viendo imágenes por aquí y por allá sin saber qué relaciones hay y qué datos, es complicado poder determinar el problema. Por ejemplo, puedes empezar haciendo los JOIN uno por uno y ver a partir de cuál es que empiezan a venir mal los datos, entonces sabrás que JOIN es el que falla.

Comment: Y ¿cómo elegir `psb_hr`entre 06 y 07?